# How to set NS records on tonic.to (tonga) registar

Tags: dns

Some guy asked how to setup the domain bought from [tonic](https://www.tonic.to/):

[his question](https://serverfault.com/questions/752543/dns-a-record-with-only-primary-secondary-nameserver-options)

since i didn't found any guide on google, i'll share how i did;

i used [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) in this case because they provide a free super fast DNS service, CDN, DDOS protection and lots of other stuff with free and premium plans

my solution below ↓

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is how i solved the problem:

1. bought a domain on [tonic](https://www.tonic.to/) (50USD/year)
2. register to this site: [freedns.afraid](http://freedns.afraid.org) or [afraid](http://afraid.org) and set their NS records into tonic interface
3. now wait until your domain will come online (up to 24hours, 4hours in my case)
4. now you can make an new account to cloudflare, and add the domain bought at tonic.to and set the cloudflare NS records
5. be patient on this process, because tonic refresh DNS records once every 6 hours or 24 hours, so you will need to wait some time before going online with cloudflare

**the point 2 is really important**, because cloudflare when check your domain, will give this error:

```
"yourdomain.to is not a registered domain (Code: 1049)"
```

thats because if you don't use a NS records when you buy the tonga domain, the domain wont work, and cloudflare wont give you their NS records until the domain will come "online", so here you will use free NS records provided by afraid

**other important thing**: sorry for bad english

also, if there is a better way to do this job, let me know :)